# Unable to connect to mysql database with google app engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, pdo, cloud

I have a Google App Engine application that is running, database is set up and should be working (works with development server), but cannot connect to the database when the app is deployed. I get the following error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in /base/data/home/apps/s~helloworldtmb/1.382580389844400668/guestbook.php on line 26 

Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=-1 in /base/data/home/apps/s~helloworldtmb/1.382580389844400668/guestbook.php on line 26 {"outcome":false,"message":"Unable to connect."}
```

line 26 is

```
 $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<helloworldtmb>:<helloworldtmb:helloo>;dbname=guestbook', 'root', 'p');
```

`helloworldtmb` is the application id and `helloworldtmb:helloo` is the instance name. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the angle brackets from the Project ID and the Cloud SQL instance name

Comment: Oh thank you didn't realise. The line is now:
         $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/helloworldtmb:helloworldtmb:helloo;dbname=guestbook', 'root', 'p');

But I am still getting the same error messages

Comment: Running out of ideas ... Have you grant the app (helloworldtmb) access to the Cloud SQL instance? as described on the step 2 of  the section [Build a starter application and database](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Build_a_starter_application_and_database).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't remove the `<angle brackets>` when filling in the template from the [docs you followed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#pdo_mysql_connecting_from_app_engine). Usually, when programming, when you see angle-brackets with words inside like "your app id" or "your database name", you'll want to interpret the angle-brackets as defining the start and end of where your string should be. So,

```
/home/<your username>/.ssh/
```

Would become

```
/home/anon/.ssh/
```

And

```
curl -X <request method> <url>
```

Would become

```
curl -X GET http://v1-dot-api.domain.com/threads/list
```

Comment: Oh thank you didn't realise. The line is now:
         $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/helloworldtmb:helloworldtmb:helloo;dbname=guestbook', 'root', 'p');

But I am still getting the same error messages

Comment: There's some peculiar character showing up like an empty square between `guest` and `book` in the dbname in this comment (same in your comment to Layo's answer).  No such peculiar character in your original Q.  Wonder if that has something to do with it...